# Change from Automatic to Manual transmission in Forza Horizon 5?

Tags: forza-horizon-5

I would like to switch to manual transmission as I would prefer to change the gears manually. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change to manual transmission by:

1. Go to the Pause menu.
2. Open 'Settings' (bottom right) in the Campaign Section.
3. Go to the 'Difficulty' tab.
4. Scroll down to 'Shifting'.
5. Change it to 'Manual' if you want manual shifting, or change it to 'Manual with clutch' if you want to make it so you need to hold another button at the same time as upshifting or downshifting.